# Hadoop: distribute mappers between available nodes

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a file containing paths to k files on hdfs and I am passing it as an input to hadoop that starts k mappers (one for each file path). Each mapper is supposed to process the file with defined filename. My question is if there is any way to ensure that hadoop will use all available nodes to handle k mappers instead of running all k nodes one by one on the single node? I need this as file processing takes significant amount of time and I really need files to be processed in parallel, but not how hadoop decides on its own.

Thanks

Comment: why don't you read the file from your driver and set the paths dynamically?

Comment: Ok, but how will it help me to use all available nodes for file processing?

Comment: It does not use all the nodes to read the file containing the paths. But assuming that is a single file it doesn't matter. Once the the paths are set from the file for the job, it will use all the nodes available